# Prove for all $λ$ contained in $k×l$ box, $w_λ=\sum_{x\in Add(λ)} w(x)-\sum_{y\in Remove(λ)} w(y)=kl-2|λ|$ is positive as long as $n=|λ|<\frac{kl}2$

Tags: combinatorics, algebraic-combinatorics

I am learning [Algebraic Combinatorics](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/18-212-algebraic-combinatorics-spring-2019/) from MIT-OCW. Doubt is from the [Lecture Notes](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/18-212-algebraic-combinatorics-spring-2019/pages/lecture-notes/)-$20$,

> PDF [Link](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/18-212-algebraic-combinatorics-spring-2019/0ec992078020a29eedabe02866230a5e_MIT18_212S19_lec20.pdf) for Notes

In Lemma $190$

> For all $\lambda$ contained in a $k\times l$ box, $$w_\lambda=\sum_{x\in Add(\lambda)} w(x)-\sum_{y\in Remove(\lambda)} w(y)=kl-2|\lambda|$$ So this is positive as long as $n=|\lambda|< \frac{kl}2$

To show the unimodality of Gaussian coefficients, the `lemma 190` is needed. The note doesn't give explicit reasoning; how can I prove it?

Comment: The image of the lemma has  undefined notation in it.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\lambda$ be a Young diagram that fits into a $k\times l$ box. Let $\textrm{Add}(\lambda)$ and $\textrm{Remove}(\lambda)$ be the squares one can add to/remove from $\lambda$ to obtain another Young diagram. Let$$w_k(i,j) = (i-j+l)(j-i+k)$$be a function of the squares of the box and let$$w_k(\lambda) = \sum_{x\in \textrm{Add}(\lambda)}w_k(x) - \sum_{y\in \textrm{Remove}(\lambda)}w_k(y).$$

We show $w_k(\lambda) = kl-2|\lambda|$ by induction on $k$. If $k=0$, everything is zero. Now let $\lambda$ fit in a $(k+1)\times l$ box, and let $\lambda'$ be the Young diagram one obtains from $\lambda$ by removing the $m'$ rows of squares that have the same number $j'$ of columns as the $(k+1)$th row. Then $\lambda'$ fits into the upper $k\times l$ subbox and by induction $w_k(\lambda')=kl-2|\lambda'|$.

Now note that the squares in $\textrm{Add}(\lambda')$ and $\textrm{Remove}(\lambda')$ can be almost paired with one another: For every addable square at $(i,j+1)$ to the right of $\lambda'$ there is a removable square at $(i+m_j,j)$, $m_j+1$ being the number of rows in $\lambda'$ of the same width as the $i$th row, and only one addable square at $(M+1,1)$ at the bottom left of $\lambda'$ remains unpaired.

(Note that since $w_k(k+1,1) = w_k(1,l+1) = 0$, the case where $\lambda'$ touches the right or bottom edges of the box doesn't have to be treated specially.)

Since$$(w_{k+1}(i,j+1)-w_{k+1}(i+m_j,j)) - (w_k(i,j+1)-w_k(i+m_j,j)) = -(m_j+1)$$and$$w_{k+1}(M+1,1)-w_k(M+1,1) = M+l,$$it follows that$$w_{k+1}(\lambda')-w_k(\lambda') = M + l + \sum_j -(m_j+1) = l,$$where $j$ ranges over the paired squares.

In terms of addable/removable squares, going from $\lambda'$ to $\lambda$ loses an addable square at $(M+1,1)$ and gains an addable/removable pair at $(M+1,j'+1), (k+1,j')$, so$$\begin{alignat*}{3}w_{k+1}(\lambda)-w_{k+1}(\lambda') &= &&-w_{k+1}(M+1,1) \\&&&+ w_{k+1}(M+1,j'+1) - w_{k+1}(k+1,j') \\ &= &&-2(k+1-M)j' \\ &=&& -2m'j' \\ &=&& -2|\lambda\setminus\lambda'|,\end{alignat*}$$and finally$$\begin{align}w_{k+1}(\lambda) &= w_k(\lambda') + (w_{k+1}(\lambda')-w_k(\lambda')) + (w_{k+1}(\lambda)-w_{k+1}(\lambda')) \\ &= kl-2|\lambda'| + l - 2|\lambda\setminus\lambda'| \\ &= (k+1)l - 2|\lambda|.\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you so much! Last evening I also came up an alternative solution. Suppose we use induction, and only care about 'local difference' of the original Young diagram and new diagram with one extra box added on it, we can then compute the $\sum_{odd}w(\lambda) - \sum_{del}w(\lambda)$ with respect to the new block added. It can be shown that the difference is -2 among several different basic cases. So the induction can be shown true. Does it make sense?

Comment: It does! It sounds simpler, actually, depending on how many cases there are.